# Javascript packing object to hash string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, hash

I have an object that is updating with every mouse click and it could be loaded with the page. I am trying to compress it into a hash ( so users can link their variations Ex:`/page#HsaWiSAU`, but I am having trouble making it into a readable link.

So far I've tried couple compressing libs but nothing. I was close with the [lz-string](https://github.com/pieroxy/lz-string/) one, but when it compresses it, there are those huge strings.

```
{
    "FX": {
        "row1": {
            "sp6111": {
                "ranks": 5,
                "curr": 1
            },
            "sp6114": {
                "ranks": 5,
                "curr": 0
            }
        },
        "row2": {
            "sp6121": {
                "ranks": 1,
                "curr": 0
            },
            "sp6122": {
                "ranks": 1,
                "curr": 0
            },
            "sp6123": {
                "ranks": 1,
                "curr": 0
            }
        }...
    },
    "CX": {},
    "RX": {}
}
```

Can you suggest me a lib I should look at or how to write my own ? I get that the large strings are because I stringify this and compress the entire string, so I need a better, more human-friendly solution.

Comment: If you want a short hash like that, then you will have to create a database of what each hash means. Otherwise there's no way to cram that much information into a tiny string like that. (Unless each JSON is only different in a few places, then you could hash just the differences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate a user friendly hash, look into [HashIds](http://hashids.org/)

Then you can easily generate a hash by passing the result of `JSON.stringify(obj)` into that library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use redis or some key value database for that.
I would prefer to use redis.